# if esle condition not working inside constructor for middleware in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, authentication, constructor, laravel-5.4, middleware

I can use only one middleware at a time..inside a constructor..I want to use if else condition inside constructor or two middleware.

I can use only only middleware inside constructor & if else condition also not working

Example are follows

If else

```
class HRJob extends Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(Auth::guard('admin'))
        {
            $this->middleware('auth:admin');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    }
    public function userdetails()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

Two middleware

```
class HRJob extends Controller
{  
    public function __construct()

        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function userdetails()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, there is no need for two middleware.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

is equivalent to whatever you are trying to do since 'auth' is still valid for 'auth:admin'.

but you can still put your middleware in the Routes files (web.php/api.php) like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:admin'],function (){
    Route::get('/', 'HRJob@userdetailsAdmin');
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function (){
    Route::get('/', 'HRJob@userdetails');
});
```

hope this helps.

---edit---

in your case, with two different table for auth and without creating a custom middleware for a "any auth", you are just missing the check() method:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
} else {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

wich is equivalent to

```
if (!Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: #N69S I want to use one function for two middleware..In your case you are using two different functions for two middleware..Your solution is working for two different function..but i want to use only one function for two middleware..

Comment: @PrashantPatil , if you want to use the two middleware for the same function, use only the "auth" middleware without the "auth:admin" one. cause when "auth:admin" is valid, "auth" is valid too.

Comment: #N69S I have two seprate table for authentication    
                                     
Following middleware pointing to diffrent table for authentiication or login
       $this->middleware('auth:admin') - admins 
        $this->middleware('auth')- user

As per your case $this->middleware('auth') pointing to only user table

I want  $this->middleware('auth:admin') pointing to admin table not user table

Comment: @PrashantPatil , now i see. The best solution would be to create a custom middleware wich will be valid for either of the authentification methods.
but using your format, you can put in the if condition "if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())"

Comment: i did this alsoyou see if esle condition there were i used "if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())" condition also if this will be true then it will be login accordingly  " $this->middleware('auth:admin')" middleware(admin login will work)..but the esle condition wont work if the "if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())" or  "if (Auth::guard('admin')"  will be executed  then $this->middleware('auth'); middleware not executing..Only one middleware working inside the constructor.according to if& else also if it will go to if condition and work fine then else condition middleware wont workingor vice-versa